# Run multiple sets of parameters Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter to record the response time of a form submission to the DB (the form is set out in the parameters request) i.e Name-Value.

If I choose 20 threads it will run the same set of parameters 20 times, but what if I want to have each thread run a different set of parameters, how would I achieve this?

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Hello, did you find answer to your issue ? Is it below ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you case you should use [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) element:

- Use sharing mode to all threads.
- Set number of threads to 20 and iteration to the number you want but you will need to have a sufficient data set.

This will give a different line to each thread, up to you to organize your data correctly.

Regards

Philippe